# create a new csv file on the press of button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i want to create a new csv file everytime when i press a button and save it with date and time stamp name.

So far this is my code but i can only append or overwrite, the file is created only once :(

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

 Dim csvFile As String = "C:\" & FindDate("", 2) & Time.Replace(":", "") &".csv" 

 Dim outFile As System.IO.StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(csvFile, False)

 outFile.WriteLine("hello")

 outFile.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"C:\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")